# Python unittest: How to raise IndexError for sys.argv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, argv, sys

I am trying to test the case where the number of parameters in the script being executed is less than three. When debugging, I see that an **IndexError** occurs, but for some reason **assertRaises** does not "see" it.
Can anyone help fix this?

**my_file.py:**

```
def my_func():
    try:
        sys.argv[2]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

**text_sys_srgv.py**

```
import sys
import unittest
import my_file
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestServer(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_func(self):
        work_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
        my_file_full_path = os.path.join(work_dir, 'my_file.py')

        test_args = [my_file_full_path, 'arg1']
        with patch.object(sys, 'argv', test_args):
            self.assertRaises(IndexError, my_file.my_func)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: my_func does not raise the exception. It catches it. assertRaises will confirm if the exception is actually thrown out of the function instead of caught internally and suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `my_func` does not raise the exception. It catches it. `assertRaises` will confirm if the exception is actually thrown out of the function, instead of caught inside it and suppressed.